# Application integration between CRM and Social Tables

Tags: social-tables

I've been tasked by one of your clients to build an integration between their CRM and Social Tables. They want to be able to send events from the CRM over to Social Tables. Is this possible to do without having to login to Social Tables every time? From what I can tell they will have to do it once and then every time the token expires. Is this true? If so is there anyway that they can login to Social Tables every X amount of days or week, get a token, and then input that token into a custom area in a CRM. Then our CRM can use that token to query to Social Tables? Please help! Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes we offer OAuth 2.0 flows. This means you can store a refresh token on the initial handshake. When that token expires you can use that to re-up the current oauth token.

Our docs are here: http://developer.socialtables.com -- We provide a few examples you can use to get started. But that would be the recommended approach.

Comment: I've gone through the documentation and must be overlooking this somewhere. Do you have a link to one of the specific examples? Thank you!

Comment: So I've read through SO and all of the documentation and might be misunderstanding how to use this API.

How do I get the access token? It seems that I have to store that to then get the refresh token? Sorry for the confusion on this but I just need to get this to work without end user interaction. Is there any .Net example code that shows how to get the correct token?

Comment: Hey there Chris. The one route you will need for your auth needs will be 
POST **/4.0/oauth/token**  
I'd recommend going to our [API Console](https://developer.socialtables.com/api-console#!/Authentication/post_4_0_oauth_token) to test your calls out.  

Your initial call will need to be made with params: 
**grant_type="password"**
**username**
**password**

This will return to you:
access_token - to make api calls for user
refresh_token - needs to be saved, used to get a new access_token once it expires

Comment: To get a new access_token, another POST to /4.0/oauth/token with params: 
**grant_type="refresh_token"**, 
**username**, 
**refresh_token**

This will return to you new: 
access_token - new token, 
refresh_token - new token needed to be saved to get next token