# Authentication via Code into Social Tables

Tags: social-tables

When I try to authenticate with grant types "client_credentials" or "password" to get a token via the developer portal and or via code I am unable to get a token and I get the following response.

"message": "The grant type is unauthorized for this client_id"

(I am providing the username and password for the named user)
[Post in Developer API console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qgpqr.png)

[Response in Developer API console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TNVS9.png)

I have provide all the fields that seem to be required. Maybe I am missing something.

I am however able to get the token when i first retrieve and Authorization code (via redirect from Social Tables and using the authorization_code grant type)

We are hoping to integrate Social Tables with an existing system that will push new registrants into social tables for seating assignments so this code will need to run as a named user on a server and make API calls to Social Tables without a user of the other application having to authenticate into social tables.

1. How do I authorized the grant type (provided that is the correct way)
   (please see [Application integration between CRM and Social Tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51844112/application-integration-between-crm-and-social-tables))

editing my original question with some example code

c# code

```
public string SocialTablesLoginUrl()
        {
            //todo need to get the AuthCode without redirecting user to another url
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(_redirectUrl)){ throw new NullReferenceException("Redirect Url is required");}
            return
                $"https://auth.socialtables.com/oauth/authorize?client_id={_clientId}&redirect_uri={_redirectUrl}&response_type=code&grant_type=authorization_code";
        }
public void SetTokenFromAuthCode(string authCode)
        {
            var client = new RestClient(_rootUrl);
            var request = new RestRequest("/4.0/oauth/token", Method.POST);
            request.AddHeader("content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
            request.AddParameter("application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
                $"client_id={_clientId}&client_secret={_clientSecret}&grant_type=authorization_code&code={authCode}&response_type=token",
                ParameterType.RequestBody);
            var response = client.Execute(request);
            var socailTableToken =
                Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<SocailTableToken>(response.Content);
            _token = socailTableToken;
        }
public TokenData GetTokenData()
        {
            var client = new RestClient(_rootUrl);
            var request = new RestRequest("/4.0/oauth/token", Method.GET);
            request.AddHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " +  _token.access_token);
            var response = client.Execute(request);
            var userData =
                Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TokenData>(response.Content);
            _userData = userData;
            return userData;
        }
public EventResponse CreateNewEvent(Event model)
        {
            var apiEndPoint = $"https://api.socialtables.com/4.0/events?team_id={_userData.team.id}";
            var data = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(model);
            var response = SocialTablesPostToEndPoint(apiEndPoint, data);
            return Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<EventResponse>(response.Content);
        }
private static IRestResponse SocialTablesPostToEndPoint(string apiEndPoint, string data)
        {
            var client = new RestClient(apiEndPoint);
            var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
            request.AddHeader("cache-control", "no-cache");
            request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
            request.AddHeader("Accept", "application/json");
            request.AddHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + _token.access_token);
            request.AddParameter("application/json", data, ParameterType.RequestBody);
            var response = client.Execute(request);
            return response;
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am posting this for any other .net developer who are attempting an intergration with social tables. Hopefull this will save you some time.

Question: Can you create an interface with out redirect the user to login to social tables.
Answer: No this is not currently supported please see the answer provide by their engineer above.

so with that out of the way here is some sample code that may help if you proceed.

Extension Methods 
I have created a couple of extension methods that help in this process

```
 public static class AppExtensions
    {
        public static double DateTimeToEpoch(this DateTime dt) => dt.ToUniversalTime().Subtract(new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc)
        ).TotalMilliseconds;

        public static dynamic GetPropValue(this object obj, string prop)
        {
            var model = obj.GetType().GetProperty(prop)?.GetValue(obj, null);
            return model;
        }
    }
```

now the helper class. Please keep in mine I am still refactoring the code to do some additional improvements and correct the misspellings but it should get you 90% there also I serialized the json to strongly typed objects (you can use something like [Json2csharp](http://json2csharp.com/)) but you can just switch those out to dynamic objects and work with those. The rest helper methods are what you may find to be the most useful. :) happy coding.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using AppExtensions;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
using RestSharp;
using SocialTablesLib.Models;

public class SocialTablesAuthentication
    {
        private readonly string _clientId;
        private readonly string _clientSecret;
        private readonly string _redirectUrl;
        private readonly string _rootUrl = "https://api.socialtables.com";
        private static SocailTableToken _token { get; set; }
        private static TokenData _userData{get;set;}
        public SocialTablesAuthentication(string clientId, string clientSecret, string redirectUrl)
        {
            _clientId = clientId;
            _clientSecret = clientSecret;
            _redirectUrl = redirectUrl;
        }

        #region Authentication Helpers
        public string SocialTablesLoginUrl()
        {
            //you will need to do this Currently Social tables does not suport this in the current version
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(_redirectUrl)){ throw new NullReferenceException("Redirect Url is required");}
            return
                $"https://auth.socialtables.com/oauth/authorize?client_id={_clientId}&redirect_uri={_redirectUrl}&response_type=code&grant_type={GrantTypes.AuthorizationCode}";
        }
        #endregion

        #region current user information
        public TokenData GetUserTokenData()
        {
            var client = new RestClient(_rootUrl);
            var request = new RestRequest("/4.0/oauth/token", Method.GET);
            request.AddHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " +  _token.access_token);
            var response = client.Execute(request);
            var userData =
                Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TokenData>(response.Content);
            _userData = userData;
            return userData;
        }
        #endregion

        #region Events
        public EventResponse CreateNewEvent(Event model)
        {
            var apiEndPoint = $"/4.0/events?team_id={_userData.team.id}";
            var data = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(model);
            var response = SocialTablesPostToEndPoint(apiEndPoint, data);
            return Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<EventResponse>(response.Content);
        }
        public List<EventResponse> GetAllEvents(string teamId)
        {                
            var response =  SocialTablesGetEndPoint($"/4.0/events/teams/{teamId}");
            var model =
                Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<EventResponse>>(response.Content);
            return model;
        }
        public EventResponse GetEventById(string eventId)
        {
            var response = SocialTablesGetEndPoint($"/4.0/events/{eventId}");
            var model =
                Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<EventResponse>(response.Content);
            return model;
        }
        #endregion

        #region GuestList
        public GuessListResponse CreateNewGuestList(GuestList model)
        {
            var apiEndPoint = $"/4.0/guestlists?event_id={model.event_id}";
            var data = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(model);
            var response = SocialTablesPostToEndPoint(apiEndPoint, data);
            return Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<GuessListResponse>(response.Content);
        }

        public List<GuessListResponse> GetGuestListByEvent(string eventId)
        {
            var response = SocialTablesGetEndPoint($"/4.0/guestlists?event_id={eventId}");
            var model =
                Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<GuessListResponse>>(response.Content);
            return model;

        }
        #endregion

        #region Guest
        public List<Guest> GetAllGuestForGuessList(string guestlistId)
        {
            var response = SocialTablesGetEndPoint($"/4.0/guestlists/{guestlistId}");
            var model =
                Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<GuessListResponse>(response.Content);
            return model.guests;
        }
        public GuestResponse AddGuestToList(Guest model, string guestListId)
        {
            var apiEndPoint = $"/4.0/guestlists/{guestListId}/guests";
            var data = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(model);
            var response = SocialTablesPostToEndPoint(apiEndPoint, data);
            return Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<GuestResponse>(response.Content);
        }

        public void DeleteGuestFromList(string guestListId, string guestId)
        {
            var apiEndPoint = $"/4.0/guestlists/{guestListId}/guests/{guestId}";
            var response = SocialTablesEndPoint(apiEndPoint, Method.OPTIONS);
            if(response.StatusCode != HttpStatusCode.NoContent) {throw new Exception("Can not Find Guest"); }

        }
        #endregion

        #region diagram
        public List<GuestAssignement> GetSeatingAssignments(string diagramId)
        {
            var model = new List<GuestAssignement>();
            var response = SocialTablesGetEndPoint($"/4.0/diagrams/{diagramId}/guests");
            var jObject = JObject.Parse(response.Content);
            var guestList = jObject["data"]["guest_seats"].Children();
            foreach (var guest in guestList)
            {
                var guestId = guest.GetPropValue("Name");
                var tableId =
                    guest.Children().ToList().FirstOrDefault()?.Children().FirstOrDefault().Values().ToList()[0];
                var tabledata = jObject["data"]["floor_elements"].Children().ToList();
                foreach (var table in tabledata)
                {
                    var tableFoundId = table.GetPropValue("Name");
                    if (tableId != null && tableFoundId != tableId.ToString()) continue;
                    var tableinfo = table.Children().FirstOrDefault()?.Children().ToList();

                    if (tableinfo == null){throw new NullReferenceException();}
                        var guestAssignement = new GuestAssignement
                        {
                            GuestId = guestId,
                            TableName = tableinfo[8].First().GetPropValue("Value").ToString(),
                            TableNumber = tableinfo[9].First().GetPropValue("Value").ToString()
                        };
                        model.Add(guestAssignement);

                    break;
                }
            }
            return model;
        }

        public List<GuestAssignement> GetSeatingAssignmentsByEventId(string eventId)
        {
            var response = SocialTablesGetEndPoint($"/4.0/diagrams?event={eventId}");
            var jObject = JObject.Parse(response.Content);
            var id = jObject["data"][0]["id"];
            return GetSeatingAssignments(id.GetPropValue("Value").ToString());
        }
        #endregion

        #region RestHelpers

        public void SetTokenFromAuthCode(string authCode)
        {
            var client = new RestClient(_rootUrl);
            var request = new RestRequest("/4.0/oauth/token", Method.POST);
            request.AddHeader("content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
            request.AddParameter("application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
                $"client_id={_clientId}&client_secret={_clientSecret}&grant_type={GrantTypes.AuthorizationCode}&code={authCode}&response_type=token",
                ParameterType.RequestBody);
            var response = client.Execute(request);
            var socailTableToken =
                Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<SocailTableToken>(response.Content);
            _token = socailTableToken;

        }
        private void RefreshToken()
        {
            var client = new RestClient(_rootUrl);
            var request = new RestRequest("/4.0/oauth/token", Method.POST);
            request.AddHeader("content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
            request.AddParameter("application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
                $"client_id={_clientId}&client_secret={_clientSecret}&grant_type={GrantTypes.RefreshToken}&refresh_token={_token.refresh_token}&response_type=token",
                ParameterType.RequestBody);
            var response = client.Execute(request);
            var socailTableToken =
                Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<SocailTableToken>(response.Content);
            _token = socailTableToken;
        }

        private IRestResponse SocialTablesPostToEndPoint(string apiEndPoint, string data)
        {
            RefreshToken();
            var client = new RestClient($"{_rootUrl}{apiEndPoint}");
            var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
            request.AddHeader("cache-control", "no-cache");
            request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
            request.AddHeader("Accept", "application/json");
            request.AddHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + _token.access_token);
            request.AddParameter("application/json", data, ParameterType.RequestBody);
            var response = client.Execute(request);
            return response;
        }
        private IRestResponse SocialTablesGetEndPoint(string apiEndPoint)
        {
            RefreshToken();
            var client = new RestClient($"{_rootUrl}{apiEndPoint}");
            var request = new RestRequest(Method.GET);
            request.AddHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + _token.access_token);
            var response = client.Execute(request);
            return response;
        }
        #endregion
        private IRestResponse SocialTablesEndPoint(string apiEndPoint, Method methodType)
        {
            RefreshToken();
            var client = new RestClient($"{_rootUrl}{apiEndPoint}");
            var request = new RestRequest(methodType);
            request.AddHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + _token.access_token);
            var response = client.Execute(request);
            return response;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, we only support `refresh_token` and `access_token` -- the docs are slightly misleading as we only support other grant types for our legacy endpoints which are no longer available.

## Handling Authentication

- When a user clicks the `Link` button in your application, redirect them to
  `https://auth.socialtables.com/oauth/authorize?client_id=APP_ID&redirect_uri=REDIRECT_URL&grant_type=authorization_code&response_type=code`

  - The APP_ID can be obtained from the "App ID" field under "https://developer-portal.socialtables.com/apps" once you have registered your application
  - The `REDIRECT_URL` is the URL Social Tables will redirect back to with the OAuth Token ready
- Once redirected the user will be prompted to log in with their Social Tables username + password
- Once the login is successful they will be redirected back to the REDIRECT_URL you specified before
- The `REDIRECT_URL` is where you can capture oauth `code` from the `code` query param

  - Example: `https://my-awesome-app.com/oauth-redirect-endpoint?code=NEWLY_GENERATED_CODE`
- In your app you will read the `code` from the query param and make a call to `https://api.socialtables.com/4.0/oauth/token` along with your `APP_ID` and `APP_SECRET`

  - Both are obtained from the developer portal
  - Swagger Docs: `https://developer-portal.socialtables.com/api-console#!/Authentication/post_4_0_oauth_token`
- In that response you will be given two tokens:

  - `access_token`: this will be set in the `Authorization` header in every request to ST
  - `refresh_token`: this needs to be stored in a *secure* location and can be used to request a new `access_token` of the current one has expired
- If there is any other questions, please follow the docs here: https://developer-portal.socialtables.com/docs/apps/tutorial

Comment: I am able to do all the above if i redirect the user with out any problem. However the registration process will be coming from our .org (Another system and possibly public facing) and not necessarily from a user. Is it possible to use a user credentials (named user) for integration between the systems? If so how? If not how do you recommend we accomplish full system iteration without having to have a manual process that involves a user.

Answer (score 0):

The registration system is not public facing.

Comment: Hey.  You are correct that you can not see the app administration interface without being logged in to Social Tables.  Fortunately, you can sign up for a free account at https://signup.socialtables.com.  After you go through the signup process and log in you can access the app management tool.